# How to loop back to start of question in case of incorrect input in a yes/no game?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create a very simple easy game with multiple rounds and each round has three questions.

If you answer the wrong answer to a question in one round, you have to start the round again from the top. Once you have answered two questions correctly, you have a final question where if you answer this right you add 1 to the answer pot. After this you move on to the next round.

I am trying to figure out how to loop back to the start of the round that you are currently on if you get an answer wrong. At the moment if you get an answer wrong in the first round, you just go straight on into the second round.

Any ideas on how I can integrate a loop into the incorrect answer statements so they start that round again before they are able to move on? Thank you!

```
def askYesNoQuestion(question):
  YesNoAnswer = input(question).upper()
  if YesNoAnswer == "Y" or YesNoAnswer == "N":
     return YesNoAnswer
  else:
      print('Please enter Y or N!')
      return askYesNoQuestion(question)


animal_answer1 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a parrot a bird? Y/N ")
if animal_answer1 == "Y":
  print("Correct!")
  animal_answer2 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a whale a mammal? Y/N ")
  if animal_answer2 == "Y":
      print("Correct! Move on")
      animal_answer3 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a kangaroo a marsupial? Y/N ")
      if animal_answer3 == "Y":
          print("We will see... let's move on")
      else:
          print("We will see... let's move on")
  elif animal_answer2 == "N":
        print("Nope! Start again")
elif animal_answer1 == "N":
    print("Incorrect! Back to the start")


food_answer1 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a carrot a vegetable? Y/N ")
if food_answer1 == "Y":
  print("Correct!")
  food_answer2 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a tomato a vegetable? Y/N ")
  if food_answer2 == "N":
      print("Correct! Move on")
      food_answer3 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a strawberry a berry? Y/N ")
      if food_answer3 == "N":
          print("We will see... let's move on")
      else:
          print("We will see... let's move on")
  elif food_answer2 == "Y":
        print("Nope! Start again")
elif food_answer1 == "N":
    print("Incorrect! Back to the start")
```

Comment: You can simply put each block in a while loop (or a for loop if you want finite number of "retries") and add the instruction `continue` whenever the  answer is incorrect to start again from the beginning of the loop, ie from the first question.

Comment: While loop will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve this would be [error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html) - create a custom `Exception` and throw it whenever a wrong answer is given. Loop until you passed all questions without exception and then break.

I also modified your ask-function , there is no need for recursion in it, simply loop and return when a valid answer is given.

```
def askYesNoQuestion(question):
    """Asks a question, accepts only Y or N as answer. Repeats until given."""
    while True:
        YesNoAnswer = input(question).strip().upper()
        if YesNoAnswer in ("Y,N"):
            return YesNoAnswer
        else:
            print('Please enter Y or N!')

class WrongAnswer(Exception):
    """Custom exception, thrown (and caught) on bad answers"""
    pass

while True:
    try:
        animal_answer1 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a parrot a bird? Y/N ")
        if animal_answer1 == "Y":
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            raise WrongAnswer()

        animal_answer2 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a whale a mammal? Y/N ")
        if animal_answer2 == "Y":
            print("Correct! Move on")
        else:
            raise WrongAnswer()

        animal_answer3 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a kangaroo a marsupial? Y/N ")
        if animal_answer3 == "Y":
            print("We will see... let us move on")
        else:
            raise WrongAnswer()

        food_answer1 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a carrot a vegetable? Y/N ")
        if food_answer1 == "Y":
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            raise WrongAnswer()

        food_answer2 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a tomato a vegetable? Y/N ")

        if food_answer2 == "N":
            print("Correct! Move on")
        else:
            raise WrongAnswer()

        food_answer3 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a strawberry a berry? Y/N ")
        if food_answer3 == "N":
            print("We will see... let us move on")
        else:
            raise WrongAnswer()

    except WrongAnswer:
        print("Meeeep, wrong - go again.\n")
    else:
        break # executes if all questions passed without raising exception  

print("Cool - all correct!")
```

Output:

```
Is a parrot a bird? Y/N y
Correct!
Is a whale a mammal? Y/N n
Meeeep, wrong - go again.

Is a parrot a bird? Y/N y
Correct!
Is a whale a mammal? Y/N y
Correct! Move on
Is a kangaroo a marsupial? Y/N y
We will see... let us move on
Is a carrot a vegetable? Y/N y
Correct!
Is a tomato a vegetable? Y/N n
Correct! Move on
Is a strawberry a berry? Y/N y
Meeeep, wrong - go again.

Is a parrot a bird? Y/N y
Correct!
Is a whale a mammal? Y/N y
Correct! Move on
Is a kangaroo a marsupial? Y/N y
We will see... let us move on
Is a carrot a vegetable? Y/N y
Correct!
Is a tomato a vegetable? Y/N n
Correct! Move on
Is a strawberry a berry? Y/N n
We will see... let us move on
Cool - all correct!
```

---

Delegating the question-correctness-testing also to `askYesNoQuestion` leads to much shorter code:

```
def askYesNoQuestion(question, answer):
    """Asks a 'question', accepts only Y or N, loops until given. 
       Raises WrongAnswer exception if different from 'answer'"""
    while True:
        YesNoAnswer = input(question).strip().upper()
        if YesNoAnswer in ("Y,N"):
            if YesNoAnswer == answer:
                return
            else:
                raise WrongAnswer()
        else:
            print('Please enter Y or N!')

while True:
    try:
        animal_answer1 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a parrot a bird? Y/N ", "Y")
        print("Correct!")

        animal_answer2 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a whale a mammal? Y/N ","Y")
        print("Correct! Move on")

        animal_answer3 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a kangaroo a marsupial? Y/N ","Y")
        print("We will see... let's move on")

        food_answer1 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a carrot a vegetable? Y/N ", "Y")
        print("Correct!")

        food_answer2 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a tomato a vegetable? Y/N ", "N")
        print("Correct! Move on")

        food_answer3 = askYesNoQuestion("Is a strawberry a berry? Y/N ", "N")
        print("We will see... let's move on")

    except WrongAnswer:
        print("Meeeep, wrong - go again.")
    else:
        break

print("Cool - all correct!")
```